# Find the optimal size for UILabel within UIBezierPath (for a pie chart)

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uitextview, pie-chart, uibezierpath

I am desperately trying to dynamically find the optimal size to draw a UILabel within a pie chart (see my outline below).

The label center should be in the middle of each piece of the pie, which is determined by the CGPoint at 1/2 radius and 1/2 pie piece (= startAngle+(endAngle-startAngle)/2).

Now the problem is, that neither the width nor the height of the UILabel are known. The width mostly depends on the label's center position (e.g. if the pie piece is the upper half circle, the width is widest). The label lines are "unlimited" (label.numberOfLines = 0) and label.text is user defined ("description" of the pie value). Only the fontSize range between minimum (6.0f) and maximum (14.0f) is defined.

I already thought of using a UITextView with the pie piece's UIBezierPath as exclusionPath, but then centering and resizing the UIFontSize won't work - at least I didn't find a way to do it.

Any hint on how to resolve this issue is much appreciated :)

[image: Pie Chart]

Comment: Are the labels supposed to be bounded by the pie lines (circumference and dividers) or can they "overflow"? What happens if a label can't fit in any configuration (it has too many lines or area too small)? Is it hidden, pushed outside, trimmed to fit, or should never happen?

Comment: The labels are bound to be within the pie pieces. If they can't fit, with the standard fontSize, they should adjustFontSizeToFitWidth until the minimal fontSize of 8.0f is reached (if the fontSize would be smaller than 8.0f the label won't be displayed at all). The latter is no problem for me, I just need help finding the maximal rectangle within the pie piece, that has a specific center (1/2 radius, 1/2 pie piece angle).

Comment: I know this is a bit old but I have kept a tab open ever since, not being able to give an answer. I've stumbled upon this repository that implements an algorithm to find a visual center of a shape: https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel